# Springboot @RestController is never used

Tags: spring-boot

I'm having trouble getting my spring-boot application working. It's just exposing a single endpoint at the moment. And it's just got a single controller to manage that. Here is the code below.

It builds fine and the tomcat server runs, I get the **Whitelabel Error Page**.

**Full error from chrome console:** Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404.

```
src
--|main
----|java
------|com.domain.myproject.api
--------|Controller             <----(this is a package in intellij)
----------|RestController.java
--------|Springboot             <----(this is a package in intellij)
----------|SpringApplication.java
```

**RESTController.java**

```java
package com.example.myproject.api.Controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class RESTController {

    @GetMapping("/view/{id}")
    public String hello (@PathVariable("id") String id){
        return "return" + id;
    }

}
```

**SpringApplication.java**

```java
package com.example.myproject.api.Springboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CustomsApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CustomsApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**pom-xml**

These are the dependencies, which I will get to use.

```xml
<dependencies>
    <!--SpringBoot Dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Camel dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ActiveMQ dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Thanks!

PS. Also get in the intellij run console. . .

```
2018-01-23 18:28:14.879 ERROR 10541 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler : Could not resolve repository 
metadata for 1234.
```

Comment: I don't know if I see anything immediately wrong. You say you just get an error page, but what is the actual error message displayed and/or error in the console logs? Are there errors on server startup?

Comment: Multiple thing could cause this. What is the url you are actually visiting and threw the error (404?)? It should be `localhost:yourport/view/1`

Also, what is in your `application.properties` file?

Comment: Yep, going to localhost:8080/view/1234. And application.properties is empty. Thanks

Comment: When the application start up, it prints the endpoints it reads. Try checking what is there (somewhere along the end).

Comment: Try adding `@RequestMapping("/v1")` to your `RESTController` and go to `localhost:8080/v1/view/1234`

Comment: nope exact same after adding /v1. Also noticed intellij is saying class @RestController is never used. thanks

Comment: Change the name of the Controller from `RESTController ` to anyting else.

Comment: Okay if I move the two files inside the same package it works. So SpringApplication.java needed to NOT be inside a package and be in the root directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Spring boot documentation [14.2 Locating the main application class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html), it is recommended that you locate your main application class in a root package above other classes.

The `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation is often placed on your main class, and it implicitly defines a base “search package” for certain items. Using a root package also allows the `@ComponentScan` annotation to be used without needing to specify a basePackage attribute. Both these annotations are defined within `@SpringBootApplication`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your problem is with the way your packages are structured, I would advise you to remove the CustomsApiApplication class from the current package to the base package which should be com.example.myproject

This [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-structuring-your-code)  really helped me